# jQuery css() function won't apply IE hack attributes

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to apply an inline-block style to an element (a div to be specific). And in order to achieve this in IE you have to use a hack:

```
$('#element').css(
    {
        'display'  :    'inline-block',    //applies inline-block to matched elements in all browsers except IE due to hasLayout bug
        'zoom'     :    1,                 //set hasLayout to 'true' in IE
        '*display' :    'inline'           //use asterisk to only apply 'inline' style to IE
    }
);
```

However, the css() function seems to present the style to the browser such that '*display' doesn't register in IE and so therefore doesn't apply the 'inline' style.

Any ideas on why and/or how to work around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it then:

```
if($.browser.msie){
    $('#element').css({'display' : 'inline'});
}
```

Comment: jQuery documentation specifically suggests using jQuery.support over jQuery.browser because .browser relies on the User-Agent which is a mess.

Comment: I saw that, but it isn't really clear as to how to go about getting browser type.

Comment: you missed his `{'zoom': 1}` :-)

Comment: @tegeril:

Ive seen that noted in the docs to but as tscully mentions - i didnt see a clear cut way to get the browser type and/or version.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is going to filter out "bad" css properties - ie. hacks when using the css function.

However, Youre in jvascript - DO THE DETECTION IN JAVASCRIPT. There is no reason to use a hack because you have all kinds of tools at your disposal to detect not only for IE but the version. Rambo's solution is adequate :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said above, jQuery's not going to let you apply invalid properties. If you need to do it anyway, put them in a CSS class and toggle the class off and on with addClass() and removeClass().

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try css('display', 'inline')

Comment: You think? I think this would be better suited as a comment.